# How to pass parameters correctly to Paid Membership Pro's pmpro_login_forms_handler_nav filter on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pass to the filter **pmpro_login_forms_handler_nav** the needed parameters to customize the navbar below a login form.
The [documentation](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/hook/pmpro_login_forms_handler_nav/) tells to pass an array with an especific format and the name of the form. So far, I tried this on my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('pmpro_login_forms_handler_nav', function (array $links, $form = 'login') {
    
    $links['a'] = array();
    $esqueceu_senha['class'] = '';
    $esqueceu_senha['href'] = 'https://www.google.com';
    $esqueceu_senha['id'] = '';
    $esqueceu_senha['target'] = '_blank';
    $esqueceu_senha['title'] = 'Testando';
    $links['a'][] = $esqueceu_senha;

      return $links;
    }, 10);
```

But on my results, instead of leaving only the link that I want on the nav, a printed array is added on the end of the nav. Like this:

**Become a member now | Lost password? | Array**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. You can pass directly the links.
No need for use an associative array the way I was using. Just remember to empty the array of links before returning it:

```
add_filter('pmpro_login_forms_handler_nav', function (array $links, $form = 'login') {
    $links = array();
    //Esqueceu a senha
    $links[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( add_query_arg( 'action', urlencode( 'reset_pass' ), pmpro_login_url() ) ), 'Esqueceu a senha?' );
    
      return $links;
    }, 10);
```